# Can I get the last word of Slow Time without joining the Stormcloaks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm working on getting all words of power to every shout and right now I have but Slow Time and Dismay to complete. I've done some research and I was wondering, is joining Stormcloaks *requisite* for getting the last word of power? I really prefer to remain neutral in the war but I also wish to complete my words collection. This community has never let me down before, so I hope it won't now. I appreciate anything helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You can not enter Korvanjund without siding with some faction in the civil war. That means either joining the Stormcloaks **or** the Imperials is your only way to get that Word of Power.

Comment: Ah, damn. Well, is there a way to leave the imperials/stormcloaks so that I may return to neutrality?

Comment: So I'm screwed as far as collecting the words of Power? :L

Comment: @user51809 just pick a side and join it.  It doesn't alter the landscape that much.  the civil war line (along with the rewards) overall were pretty disappointing imo

Answer (score 2):

You can get the 3rd slow time word without joining any civil war factions by exploiting the plate/bucket glitch that people use to teleport through walls. With a few wooden plates you can glitch through the rubble at the start of the dungeon, swing by the word wall, and glitch back through the rubble. (I'm not sure this won't permanently break the civil war quest, so I wouldn't do it unless you want the imperials and stormcloaks to remain in a stalemate.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get there (For PC) is to click on the doors (in the console) that are locked and type "unlock" to unlock them and go through the ruin.